# Where Can I Find Hex Paper Notebooks?

Tags: tools, map-making

I apologize in advance if this question isn't suited for this thread, but I thought I'd start here.

Already in my possession is a graph paper notebook, but what I seek is a HEX grid notebook.  Does anyone know of a gaming resource shop (or stationary store) that sells hex patterned notebooks?

What I would like to do is be able to (literally) draw out a few scenarios when I'm on the go.  Software is not a desired answer.

Comment: Hexagonal Graph Paper PDF Generator: http://incompetech.com/graphpaper/hexagonal/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Albatross Hexbooks and Hex Cahiers](http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/jed_mcclure) are available from Lulu (print-on-demand), and come in various grid styles and sizes, and are staple-bound to lay flat. They're designed to interoperate, so you can use a large-hex style for high-level mapping, and flesh out the details with the hexgrids in one of the smaller-scale notebooks, for example.

Comment: The link appears to be dead.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks for the warning! But the link is working for me… Try again?

Answer (score 7):

It might be quicker and simpler to print out some hex pages and have a copy shop bind them for you.

Comment: Or get a long-arm stapler and do it yourself.